# Signed/unsigned situation when converting c# to java

Tags: c#, java

I'm currently converting the following piece of code to java from c#:

```
    public static byte MakeCS(byte[] arr)
    {
        byte cs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            cs += arr[i];
        }
        return cs;
    }
```

My naive conversation is to just change the arr.Length to arr.length ;)

However this gives me incorrect checksums since java has signed bytes and c# has unsigned ones (I tried changing the c# code to sbyte and it worked fine).

What is the correct way to handkle the situation? I know I can "convert" a java byte to unsigned by bitand'ing it with 0xFF, but I'm not sure where to do this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change the return value and make the return type `int`

```
return cs & 0xFF;
```

You don't need to change the type of cs as it will give the same result whether its an `int`, `short` or `long` after using 0xFF.  You don't need to mask each value either.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    byte[] bytes = { 1, -128, -1 }; // check sum is -128 or 0x80 or 128 (unsigned)
    System.out.println("makeCS "+ makeCS(bytes));
    System.out.println("makeCS2 "+ makeCS2(bytes));
    System.out.println("makeCS3 "+ makeCS3(bytes));
}

public static int makeCS(byte... arr) {
    byte cs = 0;
    for (byte b : arr)
        cs += b;
    return cs & 0xFF;
}

public static int makeCS2(byte[] arr)
{
    int cs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int add = arr[i];
        cs += (0xFF & add);
        cs &= 0xFF;
    }
    return cs;
}

public static short makeCS3(byte[] arr)
{
    short cs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        cs += arr[i];
    }
    return cs;
}
```

prints

```
makeCS 128
makeCS2 128
makeCS3 -128
```

Comment: +1 for getting to the point better than my answer did.  Although, to clarify for the OP: Basically, the only code that differs between signed and unsigned bytes is code that uses `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>`, `/`, `%`, or `toString`.

Comment: For `<=` `>=` `<` and `>` you can add `Byte.MIN_VALUE` or `& 0xFF` For the rest you need `& 0xFF` The adding MIN_VALUE trick is useful for `long` as there isn't a larger type to cast to (other than BigInteger)

Comment: Some people prefer XORing or subtracting instead of adding, but it's all equivalent.  (Personally, I find it easier to understand what's happening with `^`, just because I don't have to reason through the overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static byte MakeCS(byte[] arr)
{
    int cs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        int add = arr[i];
        cs += (0xFF & add);
        cs &= 0xFF;
    }
    return cs;
}
```

This will truncate the sign portion of the `int` before adding it to CS, and ten truncate everything past the eight's bit once again to emulate unsigned addition.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Perhaps this is not the most efficient way of dealing with this, but I think as long as it works, it's a reasonable conversion. I doubt that the efficiency is of much concern here (unless the OP states otherwise).

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is that the OP's code _as written_ works just fine.  It's just the code that uses the OP's method that has to change its behavior.

Comment: Or, alternately, just use the OP's code as written except that you do `& 0xFF` in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting to use the entire 8 bits of the c# `byte` in order to do the sum.  In order to correctly port to Java you'll need to pick a type which has at least the same precision.  The closest type in Java is `short`.

```
public static short MakeCS(byte[] arr)
{
    short cs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        cs += arr[i];
    }
    return cs;
}
```

Note: This isn't a perfect port though.  It opens the possibility that code which would overflow in C# won't overflow in the Java version since Java `short` has more precision that C# `byte`.